# How to prove $4^n+1$ is prime number if $3^{\frac{q-1}{2}} \equiv-1 \mod q$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $q=4^n+1$.  I need to prove that if $3^{\frac{q-1}{2}} \equiv-1 \mod q$, then $q$ is prime number.

How to prove it? thanks.

Comment: For a prime divisor $p$ of $q$, consider the order of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$.

Comment: could you explain?

Comment: could you write down the steps?

Comment: What part(s) of my hint did you understand? Do you know what $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is, and what the order of an element in a group is?

Comment: @DanielFischer Do *you* see why they ask for $4^n+1$? The proof by group order/primitive element works fine for $2^n+1$ as well ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $2^n + 1$ doesn't work with $n = 1$ (for $3$), if the converse is also targeted (viz. Proth's theorem). I suspect it's that.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen See edit, if the converse is to be formulated as $3^{\frac{q-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod{q} \iff q$ is prime, $2^1+1$ would need special-casing.

Comment: Could you write the detailed steps?

Answer (score 3):

The order of $3$ in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^\times$ is a divisor of $q-1=2^{2n}$ because $3^{q-1}\equiv (-1)^2\equiv 1\pmod q$, but it is not a divisor of $\frac{q-1}{2}=2^{2n-1}$ because $3^{\frac{q-1}{2}}\equiv -1\not\equiv 1\pmod q$. Hence the order of $3$ is exactly $q-1$, especially, $(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^\times$ has at least (hence exactly)  $q-1$ elements, i.e. none of the numbers $1\le k<q$ has  a factor in common with $q$.

Comment: Well, how do you know that $Z/qZ$ is a multiplicative group at the beginning? If q is not prime, then it is not a group.

Comment: @noot $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is the multiplicative group of units in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^\times$ is always a multiplicative group, it is the group of units of the ring $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$ and has $\phi(q)$ elements.

Comment: This is as nice and simple a quasi-solution (i.e., several hints for the OP to proof/solve) as one could expect.+1